# Exception with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm working with servlet + spring. The servlet shows this exception in

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("my_config.xml");
```

This is ecxeption text:

> 28.08.2013 16:27:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [my_spring2] in context
>   with path [/test_spring2] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an
>   exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
>     at main_package.my_spring.doGet(my_spring.java:34)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   28.08.2013 16:27:59 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload INFO: Reloading Context with name [/test_spring2] has started
>   28.08.2013 16:28:00 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload INFO: Reloading Context with name [/test_spring2] is completed

Comment: Where is `my_config.xml` located in your project?

Comment: Are you using maven? Can you show us your pom.xml please?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the exception you got is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Unless you are involved in dynamic class loading and using the Java Reflection API, chances are that the ClassNotFoundException error you are getting is not from your application code but from a **referencing API**. Another common problem pattern is a wrong packaging of your application code.

Check to **see if all the jars are added to your classpath**.

Also **some jars depend on other jars** for their working. In that case you will have to add those jars too !

Comment: Thanks for answer. If error is  in a referencing API, how can I сorrect the error? Because I load all library and it all refer to project. My IDE is Eclipce. Can you show my example. I dont use maven. When I create project, I use Dinamic Web page

Comment: I don`t use maven. But how it can be, that I have loaded all jars from spring librery and project can`t find some classes?

Answer (score 0):

look at the line 34 in `main_package.my_spring.doGet(my_spring.java:34)` and see if it is referenced from local class or from an API?

If project-> build automatically is on on your eclipse if using eclipse, then you must be having class file, else you might see errors in the explorer.

most probably the class that you are referencing is from an API, if not try add jars from your project build path.